# jenkins pipeline script java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent none
   stages {
       stage ('INSTALL_IMAGE') {
           steps {
               script {
                   def command = "env.job_file --testbed-file env.testbed_file --image_file env.image_file --mail_to env.mail_to"
                   build job: 'PYATS_JOB_EXECUTOR', parameters: 
                    [
                        string(name: 'branch_name', value: env.branch_name),
                        string(name: 'pyats_job_args', value: ${command}),
                    ]
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps`

`job_file` `testbed_file` `image_file` `mail_to` `branch_name` are all string parameters defined in the jenkins pipeline project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this error because of the following line: `value: ${command}`.
The `${}` syntax is used for the groovy [String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation), and as the name implies can be used only inside double quoted (single line or multi line) strings.
The following should work:

```groovy
string(name: 'pyats_job_args', value: "${command}"),
```

However, because your value is already a parameter you do not need the string interpolation at all, you can just **use your `command` parameter directly**:

```groovy
string(name: 'pyats_job_args', value: command),
```

This is a much more simple and readable approach.